# MQTT client connects to Cloud but RN app does not

Tags: react-native, mqtt, emqx

I have an `EMQX cloud` environment where the `MQTTX` client is connecting to, this works and i can publish and receive messages.

**MQTTX Configuration**

[image]

But when trying to connect to the same service in `React-Native`, it does not work and i keep receiving `Socket Closed`, `undefined` or `Timeout` errors.

**My Code**

```js
import init from "react_native_mqtt";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

init({
  size: 10000,
  storageBackend: AsyncStorage,
  defaultExpires: 1000 * 3600 * 24,
  enableCache: true,
  reconnect: true,
  sync: {},
});

const options = {
  host: "a1b2c3d4.oxo.oco-southeast1.emqxsl.com",
  port: 8883,
  path: "/mqtt",
  id: "id_" + parseInt(id.toString()),
};
const client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(options.host, options.port, options.path, options.id);

export const App: FC<HomeStackScreenProps<"Home">> = ({ navigation, route }) => {

  const connect = async () => {
    if (client.isConnected()) {
      if (__DEV__) console.log(" - Previous client connected? ", client.isConnected());
      if (__DEV__) console.log(" - Closing previous client? ", client.disconnect());
      onConnect();
    } else {
      client.connect({
        timeout: 3,
        userName: "test",
        password: "**********",
        keepAliveInterval: 60,
        cleanSession: true,
        useSSL: true,
        onSuccess: onConnect,
        onFailure: onFailure,
        reconnect: true,
        mqttVersion: 4,
      });
      console.log(client);
      setStatus("isFetching");
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: We probably need the actual stack traces for the errors for them to be helpful, but MQTTX is connecting to MQTT over TLS, but you don't appear to be telling the React app to use TLS and you are including options for MQTT over WebSockets ('path')

Comment: Thank you for the response, i do not get stack traces. Only a log `{"errorCode": 8, "errorMessage": "AMQJS0008I Socket closed.", "invocationContext": undefined}`. I was thinking it was going to be the protocol because indeed on MQTTX i do not have to fill in a path. I will research this more, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this problem is basically using a whole other library which supports `mqtts` protocols. I used `react_native_mqtt` which was fine at first but did not work with an online service like `emqx cloud`. so I changed my whole process to the library `sp-react-native-mqtt`. With some small, only every file that uses `MQTT`, code changes it worked perfectly!

**My code**

```js
import MQTT from "sp-react-native-mqtt";

const new_client = MQTT.createClient({
  clientId: options.clientId,
  uri: "mqtts://a1b2c3d4.oxo.oco-southeast1.emqxsl.com:8883",
  host: "a1b2c3d4.oxo.oco-southeast1.emqxsl.com",
  port: 8883,
  protocol: "mqtts",
  tls: true,
  keepalive: 60,
  clean: true,
  auth: true,
  user: "xoxo",
  pass: "xoxo1234",
});

export const App: FC<HomeStackScreenProps<"Home">> = ({ navigation, route }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    new_client
      .then((client) => {
        client.on("closed", () => {
          console.log("mqtt.event.closed");
        });

        client.on("error", (msg) => {
          console.log("mqtt.event.error", msg);
          onFailure(msg);
        });

        client.on("message", (msg) => {
          console.log(msg)
        });

        client.on("connect", () => {
          onConnect();
          // You can access new_client.publish here
          client.publish("test", "test", 0, false);
        });

        return client; // return the client for further chaining
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);
return (
   // Some components
)
}
```

Eventually after many debugging on `Android` it worked on both platforms and was connected to the `EMQX Cloud`. The comment of `hardillb` was part of the solution. With this library, the protocol is `mqtts` which is needed to connect to `EMQX Cloud`. One can also use websockets but I had to use mqtts.